# XSLT: 'Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation' appears in Oxygen tool

Tags: xslt, oxygenxml

Before all, my question is not duplicate to :
[How to fix 'Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation' in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150005/how-to-fix-errors-were-reported-during-stylesheet-compilation-in-xslt)

The problem:

I run my code with oxygen editor tool. using Saxon-HE 9.8.0.12 debugger engine.

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
                <xsl:include href="Global Variables.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/basicText.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/case.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/figure.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/links.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/list.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/text.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/basicDataTypes/wcn.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/dispatch/commonDispatch.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/limit/limit.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/procedure/action.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/procedure/condition.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/procedure/context.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/procedure/failureConsequence.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="common/procedure/nonNormalProcContent.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="DataManagement/DmStatus.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="DataManagement/Pm.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="DataManagement/PmStatus.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="Dispatch/DispatchItem.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="Dispatch/SystemFault.xsl" />
                <xsl:include href="System/SystemDescription.xsl" />

                <xsl:template match="/">
                                <html>
                                                <head>
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="special elements.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/basicDataTypes/basicText.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/basicDataTypes/list.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/basicDataTypes/wcn.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/dispatch/commonDispatch.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/limit/limit.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/procedure/context.css" />
                                                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/procedure/failureConsequence.css" />
                                                </head>
                                                <body>
                                                                <xsl:comment>
                                                                                This is a comment!
                                                                </xsl:comment>
                                                                <xsl:apply-templates />
                                                                <hr />
                                                </body>
                                </html>
                </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the code I got error:"Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation"

Where is the problem?

Comment: You should include the error. There should be a window in oxygen which shows all errors and warnings. Alternatively it is an error with your configuration e.g.: "can not find the input xml"

Comment: There is another error mesaage: 
"Required item type of document-order sorter is node(); supplied expression ($exists_lc=0and$exists_lec=0) has item type xs:boolean."  Is the message I presented in the title really just a general message, and will always be accompanied by detailed messages? If so, then fine - I will continue to seek help on the second message ...

Comment: Yes, the message reported in your title is just a summary of what happened. For the detail you need to look in the message window.

Answer (score 1):

Change `xsl:output method="html" version="1.0"` to `xsl:output method="html" version="5"`, I don't think Saxon supports a `html` serialization for HTML 1.0, `5`, `5.0` and `4.01` should be supported.

For any other errors resulting from all those included stylesheet modules you will need to take it step by step and check each module on its own first.

Comment: I changed to: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
and still got the error: 'Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation'. Is this just a general error?
Because I also have another specific error

Comment: Yes, this is a general error. And you should look at the particular errors to see why compilation failed.