# Download of Saxonica for .NET has .jar files

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I downloaded the Saxon-HE 9.9 from SourceForge from the link on this page: 
https://www.saxonica.com/download/dotnet.xml

When I unzip it, all I see is .jar files and the doc and notices.

Should I expect to see a .exe or .dll?  Or do I need to install Java to run on a Windows platform? Are the links messed up or did I download the wrong version?

Also, the 9.9 and 9.8 link to the same download named: SaxonHE9-9-1-7J.zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrolled down to Project Activity - and found link to 
"Released /Saxon-HE/9.9/SaxonHE9-9-1-7N-setup.exe" which goes to this page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.9/SaxonHE9-9-1-7N-setup.exe/download

(download file name: SaxonHE9-9-1-7N-setup.exe)

Comment: The default download link on the sourceforge project for Saxon-HE points to the Java version. As mentioned further down the page is the exe file for the .NET version. We will try to make this point on our website.

Comment: @ond Thanks.  But the .NET link on the Saxonica page also points to the Java link, which is confusing.   Why have separate links if they go to the exact page.  Maybe just link directly to the download rather than the page, if Sourceforge allows it? If 1000s of people do the same, it's a lot of time wasted.

Comment: Yes true. Some of the resources files maybe be useful that is why we take you to the project directory. We will look to simplify the organisation of files and directories shortly.